# Creating belongs_to and has_many routes, controllers, and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, user-defined-functions, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm creating a project that allows users to sign in and refer other users once they are signed in.  The users have_many referrals and the referrals belongs_to users.  I would like to have a page that, once a current user signs in, they can input a referral with the params: name, and referral_email.  But this is a collaborative project, and the person who set up the user authentication used devise. Currently, I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `resource' for #<ReferralsController:0x007fb75735aa00>
```

User Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
```

end

Referral Controller:

```
class ReferralsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @referral = Referral.new
end

def create

    @referral = current_user.referrals.new(referral_params)

    if @referral.save
        redirect_to @referral
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @referrals = current_user.find_by_user_id(params[:user_id]).referrals.all
end

def index
  @referrals = current_user.referrals.all
end

def edit
    @referral = Referral.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @referral = Referral.find(params[:id])

  if @referral.update(referral_params)
    redirect_to @referral
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @referral = Referral.find(params[:id])
  @referral.destroy

  redirect_to referral_path
end

private
  def referral_params
    params.require(:referral).permit(:name, :email, :user_id)
  end

end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      has_many :referrals
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  include RoleModel

#  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :school_name, :sport, :roles, :roles_mask

  roles_attribute :roles_mask

  roles :admin, :coach, :guest



end
```

Referral Model

```
class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

User view:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :school_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :school_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :sport %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :sport %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Referral view:

```
<h2>Refer a coach </h2>

<%= form_for ([current_user, @referral]), :html => { :mulitpart => true } do |f| %>

  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

   <div><%= f.label :referral %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :referral %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :referral_email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :referral, autofocus: true %></div>


  <div><%= f.submit "Refer This Coach" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
  Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :users do
      resources :referrals
  end

  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'




  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: Remove 'referrals' as a nested route under 'users'. Since it always applies to the current user, it should be a simple resource - not nested.  Also, your referrals#show action logic is questionable, you may want to look that over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from the `devise_error_messages!` in your referrals view - remove it.  Only the `user` resource is set up to work with devise, nothing else.

As stated in the comments, you should reconsider having referrals be a nested resource under users - there isn't really any advantage to do so the way you are using it, and lots of room for error.  Keep it simple!

Comment: Thanks! but now I'm getting undefined method `referral' for #<Referral:0x007fccce869a78> in the new referral view

Comment: That's coming from this code in your view `<%= f.label :referral %>` (as well as the text_field on the next line).  The `:referral` attribute apparently doesn't exist in your Referral model (which makes sense).  Please post the attributes that exist in your Referral model that may reflect the data entered on this form.